# C++ Classes, Basic overloading errors

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to make a program that makes a class called student that as a student ID, an array of grades, and a number showing how many grades are in the array. The class is supposed to have member methods that enter a student ID number, enter a single test grade and update the total number of grades entered, and compute an average grade and display the student ID followed by the average grade. Here is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    int StudentID;
    double Grades[5];
    int NumberOfGrades;

    // Member functions declared here
    int setID(int id);
   double setGrades(double g[5]);
   double getAverage(void);
};

// make them functions work, son.


int Student::setID(int ID)
{
    cout << "Please enter in the student's ID number: ";
    cin >> ID;
    return 0;
}

double Student::setGrades(double g[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter in grade number " << i ;
        cin >> g[i];
        NumberOfGrades++;
    }
    return 0;
}

double Student::getAverage(void)
{
    int sum = 0,average;  // declare what I need in average
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + Grades[i];
    }
    average = sum / NumberOfGrades;

    cout << "The average for " << StudentID << " is " << average;
    return 0;
}


int main ()
{
    Student Student1;

    Student1.setID; //  error
    Student1.setGrades; //  error
    Student1.getAverage();

}
```

I am getting the error saying that it cannot resolve the address of overloaded function. Can someone explain to me what an overloaded fuction is, in simplest terms possible? Also, if possible, could anyone explain why I got that error in my code?

Comment: Please post the exact error.

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: `setID` and `setGrades` both take arguments, but you're not supplying any.

Comment: This is the exact error I am getting

..\src\Gav.cpp:57:16: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
  Student1.setID; //  error
                ^
..\src\Gav.cpp:58:20: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
  Student1.setGrades; //  error
                    ^

I am using Eclipse IDE with MIN GW compiler I think...

Comment: Plus, your settings aren't doing anything at all. They're modifying a local variable (not the class's member), then returns a dummy number.

Comment: You have defined `setID` and `setGrades` with a parameter. When you call them from `main()` without parameters, you actually call other functions (the overloading ones), but they are not found in the class. Overloading is the base of Object oriented programming. See [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/76-function-overloading/).

Comment: By local variable, do you mean the ones that I have when I am making what the functions do?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to actually **call** these functions:

```
Student1.setID -> Student1.setID()
Student1.setGrades -> Student1.setGrades()
```

That's not enough, though, these function require arguments (int and double[5], respectively). So:

```
int id = 65;
double grades[5] = { 3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.5 };

Student1.setID(id);
Student1.setGrades(grades);
```

This will only remove compiler errors, though. Perhaps you don't see this, but your functions are implemented incorrectly:

```
int Student::setID(int ID)
{
    cout << "Please enter in the student's ID number: ";
    cin >> ID; //you fill ID, which is a temporary variable!
    return 0;
}
```

Also, if you ask user inside `setID()` for id, what is the purpose of this parameter? Remove it - change `setID(int ID)` to `setID()`:

```
int Student::setID()
{
    int input_id;
    cout << "Please enter in the student's ID number: ";
    cin >> input_id;
    this->StudentID = input_id;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought that when I made the member fuctions, I let the user enter in individual arguements using cin

Comment: Yes, but: 1) you don't need that parameter in this case, 2) you don't set this value, you only save it in temporary variable, class member remains unchanged. See updated answer. Other function are also implemented incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few major problems with the code:

```
int Student::setID(int ID)
{
    cout << "Please enter in the student's ID number: ";
    //ID is local. Assigning any value to it will have no effect on the class
    cin >> ID;
    //You might as well not return anything if the function is purely impure
    return 0;
}
```

The other issue is a "setter" shouldn't be taking input from a user, and doing an assignment; those are 2 separate tasks. I'd set up this function as:

```
void Student::setID(int ID)
{
    StudentID = ID;
}
```

Notice that we're assigning to the StudentID a value passed in as an argument. Use like:

```
//In main
Student student;
int newStudentID = 1234;
student.setID(newStudentID);
```

Comment: I see.. Sort of. So if I am understanding correctly, I have to implement what the user enters in my main, not the actual functions? Sorry for such naive questions, I'm just starting to learn how to code.

Comment: @ThomasPham Typically, any function should generally have 1 job. You may have a function that sets the ID, and you may have another that asks the user for an ID. It's not good practice to have a function that does both because that function becomes very limited in what it can do. What if you already have an ID, and you just want to set it without asking the user for it? Just a note on arguments: the `(int ID)` part at the top of the function is where you're passing in data. ID is what you want to set the student's ID as, and StudentID is what you want to set.

Comment: @ThomasPham Another example is the getGrades function. Instead of directly displaying the grades using `cout` from inside the function, the function should return the average so it can be displayed elsewhere. Again, what if you wanted to get the average without displaying it directly? Your current code doesn't allow that.

Comment: Ahhh I see. So for my setGrades function, I would have to  somehow copy an array that was made in the main to the fuction?

Comment: The entirety of what I need to explain would be near impossible to explain in these comments. Please don't take offence to this, but you need to study more before you can code. Specifically, look up parameters/arguments to understand how they work. Short answer to your question: yes, you could pass in an array, but there are far better ways of achieving the same goal.

Comment: None taken, I will try my best to go through my book a bit more and see what I'm doing wrong. Thank you so far, though!!

Comment: @ThomasPham No problem. For the time being, I would not worry about classes. Set up a test program with just a `main`, and play around with passing data into functions you write, and dealing with the return value. At this stage, throwing classes into the mix will only complicate things.